# How to get selected row using ReactDataGrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a very simple example of a ReactDataGrid component. I'm trying to get the selected row, but I am unsure of the syntax to get that out when calling my function.

I don't think this is the correct syntax to call, *onSelectionChange* to print out the selected row. What is the correct syntax?
*onSelectionChange={({ selected }) => this.onSelectionChange(selected)}*

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';

class DataGridExample extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    columns: PropTypes.array,
    rows: PropTypes.array
  };

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      columns: [],
      rows: []
    }
    this.rowGetter = this.rowGetter.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      rows: [
        {key: 'd1', lname: 'Doe', quantity: 3},
        {key: 'd2', lname: 'Simmons', quantity: 97},
        {key: 'd3', lname: 'Walters', quantity: 6}
      ],
      columns: [
        {name: "Quantity", key: "quantity"},
        {name: "Last Name", key: "lname"}
      ]
    }));
  }

  rowGetter(i) {
    return this.state.rows[i];
  }

  onSelectionChange = (selected) => {
      console.log(`selected:${selected}`)
  }

  render() {
    return  (
    <ReactDataGrid
      columns={this.state.columns}
      rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
      rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
      minHeight={400} 
      onSelectionChange={({ selected }) => this.onSelectionChange(selected)}
      />);
  }
}

export default DataGridExample;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/old/docs/ReactDataGrid#onrowclick

wrong param to use. do it this way. using param onRowClick, see documentation link for other params, you can also use onCellSelected

```js
  onSelectionChange = (sel) => {
    this.setState({selected:sel});
    console.log(`slected:${sel}`)
  }
  
  onCellSelected = (sel) => {
    for (var k in sel) {
      console.log(`k:${k}, ${sel[k]}`)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return  (
    <ReactDataGrid
      columns={this.state.columns}
      rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
      rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
      minHeight={400} 
      onRowClick={this.onSelectionChange}
      onCellSelected={this.onCellSelected}
  }
```